# What do the \$E\$ and \$B\$ fields look like around a length of pipe, excited from one end by a Class A amplifier?

Tags: electromagnetism, python

Diagram here:

[image: diagram]

I'm looking for help modeling the \$\mathbf{E}\$ and \$\mathbf{B}\$ fields around a length of pipe.  One end of the pipe is connected to the collector of a transistor in a Class A amplifier.  For simplicity's sake, let's say the pipe is \$1\$ meter long.

I know the voltage at the collector swings between \$0\$ V and \$2 V_{cc}\$.

$$V_c = V_{cc} (1 + \cos(\omega t))$$

$$\mathbf{E} = -\text{grad }V$$

$$\text{curl }\mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t} + \mu_0 \mathbf{J}$$

I think most of the magnetic field will be induced by the \$\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}\$ term, because very little current flows through the pipe.  Does any current flow through the pipe?

Does the voltage on the pipe change "all at once", or does the change in voltage propagate along the length of the pipe, the way a wave propagates down a transmission line?  Will it reflect when it reaches the other end?  Can we get standing waves?

What does the electric field look like around the pipe?  The magnetic field?

This is not meant to be a quarter-wavelength antenna; it is not meant to radiate.  Although, I suppose, at some frequency, it will be a good radiator.

I am a ham radio operator, call sign KG7ARW.  I am interested in the physics related to resonators, such as lumped-element LC circuits, as well as things like cavity resonators.

Can you recommend software for modeling the fields?  I know C, Javascript, and Python.  Would Meep FDTD be appropriate for modeling this situation?

EDIT:  26 Sept 2021

Is the next step to compute:

$$\text{curl }\mathbf{E} = - \frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$

$$\text{curl }\mathbf{E} =  \det
    \begin{vmatrix}
    \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
    \mathbf{E_x} & \mathbf{E_y} & \mathbf{E_z} \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

Write out the determinant of that matrix:

$$  \det
    \begin{vmatrix}
    \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
    \mathbf{E_x} & \mathbf{E_y} & \mathbf{E_z} \\
    \end{vmatrix}  =  - \frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}
$$

Integrate with respect to time:

$$  \int {\det
    \begin{vmatrix}
    \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
    \mathbf{E_x} & \mathbf{E_y} & \mathbf{E_z} \\
    \end{vmatrix} dt}   =  - \int {\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t} dt} 
$$

Solve for the B field:

$$ - \int { \det
\begin{vmatrix}
    \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
    \mathbf{E_x} & \mathbf{E_y} & \mathbf{E_z} \\
    \end{vmatrix} dt
} = \mathbf{B}
$$

$$ - \int {(\text{curl }\mathbf{E})}dt = \mathbf{B} $$

Is that the correct procedure to solve the problem?  I'm going to try doing it symbolically with Python, using the SymPy library.

With respect to my original drawing:  In which direction do the Electric Field lines point?  Do they emanate out of the cylinder in all directions, normal to its surface?  In which direction does dE/dt point?  If the Magnetic Field is going to form a circle around the cylinder, like a wagon wheel, having the cylinder as its axel, then wouldn't dE/dt be parallel with the length of the cylinder?  How is this possible, if the E field lines are pointing outwards in all directions?

EDIT 2:

Here is the Python code I wrote, for an example Electric field which is sinusoidal, and exists only in the Y-direction:

The math is based on this informative Youtube video:
https://youtu.be/MrEih3XPoMY

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sympy import *
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.vector import divergence
from sympy.vector import curl
from sympy import diff
from sympy import exp
from sympy import integrate
from sympy import I, pi

from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D


R = CoordSys3D('R')

#  Variables
X, Y, Z = symbols('X Y Z')
X = R.x
Y = R.y
Z = R.z

#  Basis Unit Vectors
i,j,k = symbols('i j k')
i = R.i
j = R.j
k = R.k

#  Symbols
x,t = symbols('x t')

Ex = smp.Function('Ex')(x,t)
Ey = smp.Function('Ey')(x,t)
Ez = smp.Function('Ez')(x,t)

wavenumber = symbols('k')
E_0 = symbols('E_0')         #  Amplitude of E field
w = symbols('w' , real=True, positive=True)



#  Define Ey(x,t)
#  Note:    I = sqrt(-1)
Ey = E_0 * smp.exp( I * (wavenumber*X - w*t ))

#  The Electric Field
E = Ex*i + Ey*j + Ez*k



init_printing(use_unicode=True, wrap_line=False)



#  curl E   =   - dB/dt
#  integrate( (curl E) , t )   =   - B


jimmy = curl( E )
B = -integrate( jimmy, t )
pprint( B )
pprint( B.simplify() )
```

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic:  Or possibly [Ham.SE], though I agree that Electrical Engineering might be a better fit.

Comment: At low frequencies,  you can use a “lumped model”. The pipe is one plate of a capacitor, the other plate being ground.  At higher frequencies, you can use a “transmission line” model. A wave is launched  at the transistor end and reflects off of the open line at the right side.  At higher frequencies, the pipe becomes an antenna, the waves escape from the pipe and actually move through the air, away from the pipe and the circuit.